# Django rest framework custom search

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a drf viewset like this

```py
class EntryViewSets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Entries.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EntrySerializer
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
    search_fields= ('desc',)
    filter_backends = (CustomSearchFilter,)
```

Here I want to search the `desc` field which is of type `models.TextField`. The search works, but I want to add some condition to the searches. I want to match the search with the query but only if the match  does not contain a `#`.

For example, lets say I have two entries with `desc`, `test new` and `test #new`.
Now if I do this query `?search=test` it returns both and `?search=new` also returns both. But I want the second query to only return the first entry i.e. `test new`, not `test #new` as it starts with `#` it should be discarded. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can override `filter_queryset` method of `CustomSearchFilter` and filter records where `desc` field matches a pattern of text with words beginning with `#`.

```py
def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
    qs = super().filter_queryset(request, queryset, view)
    qs = qs.exclude(desc__regex=r'#new')
    return qs
```

Comment: For `?search=new` I want to exclude all that contains `#new` only, but I want to include others like, I want to include strings like `#another`, for example. Your answer exclude all of them that has `#`

Comment: You can replace the pattern the regular expression pattern  with `#new`.